# Product not adding to the cart

Tags: cart

Once we add the product to our cart . It does not add the same, instead says your cart is empty. I am a novice in the same. Please if someone could help me step by step.

Thanks

Comment: check your console and network tab to know the issues.....

Comment: also check error log

Comment: No errors its showing.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the **browser's console** for errors as well as the log files in the **var** folder of Magento. If there are any, then you need to fix those errors.

If it does not help, **change the theme** from the backend of Magento to **Luma** or **Blank** theme and check the frontend.

If you don't find the error with the default theme applied, then there may be something missing in your custom theme.

You may try to **rename the files included on that page** one by one in your theme to identify the culprit.

If after applying the Luma or Blank theme you still get the same problem, then you may need to compile Magento and deploy static content.

Comment: Am a novice. Is there not one reason for this happening?

Comment: I have suggested the way to debug. In the best case, the first step should give you a clue.